# Laravel how to generate a random user ID of six different integers

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

please help me. I want to change the current auto-incrementing user ID that starts from 1 and gets incremented by 1 for each new user of the users in Laravel, to be six different random integers for example 414521 and to be unique. I would like the six random numbers ID of a user, to be generated when the user is created, help me, please.

Should I use mt_rand(0, 6) and if yes, where should I actually implement it?

```
MySQL Users Table
+-------------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type            | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                | bigint unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name              | varchar(255)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| email             | varchar(255)    | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| role              | varchar(255)    | NO   |     | user    |                |
| isActive          | tinyint         | NO   |     | 1       |                |
| email_verified_at | timestamp       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| password          | varchar(255)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| remember_token    | varchar(100)    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at        | timestamp       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at        | timestamp       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| status            | tinyint(1)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+---------------
```

UsersController.php

```
  public function store(Request $request){
       $request ->validate([

        'name' => 'required|min:6',
        'email' => 'required',
           'role'=>'required',
           'password' => '',
           'confirm_password' => '',
       ]);
```

migrations file of users

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name')->nullable();
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('role')->default('user');
            $table->boolean('status');
            $table->tinyInteger('isActive') -> default(1);
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Comment: did you read about UUID ?
more info to use it with models 
https://kim-jangwook.medium.com/use-uuid-as-primary-key-of-laravel-eloquent-orm-82e3db36cb62

Comment: Yes, I did, but if I use UUID, how can I actually set the ID to be six random integers only?

Comment: 6 integer random unique and increment , it need a logic to create from time i think (Server Time) but if not exactly 6 there is 2 ways 
uniqid(); -- it include letter , then we can hex it 
hexdec(uniqid());   -- but sure it's more than 6 and it's not increment

Comment: If you want a random `int`, consider [mt_rand](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php).

Comment: 6 number characters would limit the maximum number of possible ids to 999999, is that okay?

Comment: Yes, it is, however, should I use mt_rand() with UUID or should I implement it in the migration file directly? Please help me

Comment: quite frankly i dont understand why you want to do this in the first place, what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: your table is auto_increment you can't have random ID , if you want keep thing as it is you need just set the start of auto_increment to 99999 then first user will be 100000 and next 100001 and this is not random but it's 6 integer and incrmenet

Comment: In theory, there's nothing wrong with having a 6 digit, random integer for each User record, but in practice, implementing and relying on that for any kind of uniqueness constraint is a bad idea. As stated, you're limiting yourself from the get-go to a set number of possibilities, generating these will quickly become performance heavy, and eventually possibly an infinite loop when you run out (generate > check > save or regenerate > check > save > ...), etc etc. Take a step back and evaluate if you really need to do this, otherwise, use regular auto-increment or UUID logic.

Answer (score 0):

The ID can remain an integer. The problem lies in it having exactly six digits and still be unique, so 100000 to 999999.

You need a unique seed, and if you never delete a user, that could be the number of users (1 to 899999). You then transform this number into a number from 100000 to 999999. Possibly something could be done using a variation of the Feistel cipher, or a XOR followed by a deterministic shuffle. However, sequential IDs will be recognizably sequential.

A different approach would be to create a reverse ID table containing a six-digit integer X. The table holds 899999 records - that should be around 4 megabytes, so I think that's acceptable. When you need an ID, you `SELECT X FROM reverseID ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1`, then `DELETE FROM reverseID where X=value`. The ID will always be six digits since that's what you put into reverseID, you always know how many IDs are still available, and new IDs will be chosen at random.